# Cannot connect to any wifi network in kali linux

Tags: networking, wifi, kali-linux

I tried to test aircrack tool on my college wifi.
I have installed kali linux in virtual machine and was using USB wifi in kali linux to scan wifi network
the scanning was successful but now i cannot connect to any wifi network using my wifi usb in kali linux

My terminal reads this and not any wifi network is shown

```
root@kali:~# ifconfig
eth0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 08:00:27:b3:a2:59  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 4  bytes 240 (240.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4  bytes 240 (240.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether de:90:3a:c8:63:0d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

root@kali:~# iwconfig
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off

root@kali:~#
```

i have rebooted my machine and even used several network restarting command but can not connect to any wifi network

[image: wifi networks not visible]

Comment: Just a note that using such a tool on a network without the owners permission would be illegal in many countries.

Comment: We're going to need logs. Can you connect to networks from the host,  using the USB? Also, again, running these things on college networks is a bad idea.